# Why does CopyFromScreen give different results for full-screen game on different machines?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, screenshot

I'm using the code below to take a screenshot of all the active displays combined.

```
Rectangle totalSize = Rectangle.Empty;

foreach (Screen s in Screen.AllScreens)
    totalSize = Rectangle.Union(totalSize, s.Bounds);

Bitmap screenShotBMP = new Bitmap(
    totalSize.Width, totalSize.Height,
    PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

Graphics screenShotGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(
    screenShotBMP);

screenShotGraphics.CopyFromScreen(
    totalSize.Location.X,
    totalSize.Location.Y,
    0, 0, totalSize.Size,
    CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

I've tested this on two different machines so far, and when World of Warcraft is running full-screen one machine takes a picture of the WoW screen and the other one takes a picture of the desktop. I wouldn't have been surprised if this code *never* worked to take a screenshot of WoW, because (I assume) it uses DirectX to write directly to the video card. However, since it **does** work in one case, I'd like to know if there's something I can change in the code and/or the machine configuration to make it work in all cases. (For WoW, at least. I realize there are probably many other games that won't work.) It doesn't seem to be a framework version issue, as I have compiled my code against different versions and the behavior doesn't change.

Machine #1, which takes the WoW picture, is running 64-bit Win7 Professional and has .NET Framework versions 2.0 thru 4.0 installed.

Machine #2, which takes the desktop picture, is running 32-bit Win7 Home Premium SP1 with .NET Framework versions 1.0 thru 4.0 installed.

**Edited to add:** Another data point is that if I switch Machine #2 from a Win7 Aero desktop theme to the "classic" theme, I start getting WoW pictures instead of desktop pictures.

Comment: Is it possible that Wow itself has a different configuration on the two machines, like the video settings?

Comment: I just checked, and WoW is a 32-bit application on both machines. Could the explanation be that because the program is running in the 32-bit subsystem, the 64-bit CLR is able to capture its video?

Comment: I think games will only write directly to the video memory if a suitable graphics accelerator is installed with drivers and the game is running full screen.

Comment: Video settings are the same on both WoW installs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a call to:

```
DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION);
```

as per the answer to [Enabling/Disabling Aero from a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280480/enabling-disabling-aero-from-a-windows-service), and that fixes the problem. I don't really understand why, however.